# Disable Blog and SkyDrive for everyone in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: my-site, blog

We are using sharepoint 2013 and for some reason we want to hide blog and skydrive from mysite.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If it is really just about hiding, than you can achieve this with CSS.

```
    #suiteLinksBox ul.ms-core-suiteLinkList>li:nth-child(2) { display : none }
```

and something similar for the blog in the left navigation.

Comment: Thanks @Markus, I really want to disable them but I thought hiding might be easier. How about Disabling them?