# Yammer and onedrive questions!

Tags: yammer, onedrive-for-business

We all know microsoft is not going to develop the social stuff anymore on SharePoint, direction moving forward is use yammer, so I have a few questions:

1. If a person leaves the company and he has a yammer account, how can we have control and delete that account?
2. Apparently management doesn't want to have onedrive, because they already use My Documents, and they back up each device my documents folder on a daily basis, is it possible to disable onedrive?

Comment: This question should be split in to two questions, since they are not really related :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if one can actually disable/remove OneDrive integration in SP2013, but you could at least remove the link, as mentioned [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98546/disable-blog-and-skydrive-for-everyone-in-sharepoint-2013/98578#98578) and for your convenience:

If it is really just about hiding, than you can achieve this with CSS.

```
    #suiteLinksBox ul.ms-core-suiteLinkList>li:nth-child(2) { display : none }
```